# Maven build two copies: one with lib shaded in, one without

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project that uses the maven-shade plugin to bundle a common-code-library jar into several distributed software plugins I make.

These plugins are all for the same main application - so when someone uses more than one plugin, it becomes a problem because each plugin has a copy of the shaded lib and they're not always using the same version.

I'm not sure how to resolve this. Is there a way I can configure maven to make two builds - one with the library shaded in, and one without? For the one without, we'll provide only one copy of the library needed as a separate resource.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                    // our common lib
                </includes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my issue is to `relocate` the classes I'm shading, so they won't load copies found in other jars:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `finalName` configuration property of shade plugin. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html). It's just overwriting your original package. If you change the output name both packages will be left.

You can use something like

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <finalName>${build.finalName}-nodep.jar</finalName>
</configuration>
```

You can alternatively change `outputFile` or `outputDirectory`

Also if you want to preserve original artifact name but use classifier set `shadedArtifactAttached` to `true`.